# Based on a true match paste data fr0m one spreadsheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CmdBtnUpdate_Click()
'This is the section to pull the updated FUZE information from the dump.
Dim FUZEProjectIDMAIN As String
Dim FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP As String
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim lRow, cRow As Long
lRow = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
For j = lRow To 1 Step -1
    FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A" & j)
    'Now that I have my cell value I need to find this in Sheets("Main")
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Main").Range("B:B").Find(FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
    
    'This is where I am stuck...I want to COPY from my sheet FUZE Dump cells A to H _
    to MAIN cells B to I but I don't know how to define the Range without it throwing an error _


    Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A:H").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("MAIN").Range("B:H").Paste
    
    Else
    MsgBox "Range not found"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

So here is where I am stuck. I go through the FUZE Dump spreadsheet row by row, look in Main spreadsheet and "FIND" a matching row. This seems to work okay, but now I need to copy cells A to H from FUZE Dump to cells B to I on the matching row found in Main, just not sure how to define the "Range" for each.

```
Private Sub CmdBtnUpdate_Click()
'This is the section to pull the updated FUZE information from the dump.
Dim FUZEProjectIDMAIN As String
Dim FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP As String
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim lRow, cRow As Long
lRow = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
For j = lRow To 1 Step -1
    FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A" & j)
    'Now that I have my cell value I need to find this in Sheets("Main")
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Main").Range("B:B").Find(FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then

    'This is where I am stuck...I want to COPY from my sheet FUZE Dump cells A to H _
    to MAIN cells B to I but I don't know how to define the Range without it throwing an error
    Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A" & j & ":H" & j).Copy Destination:=MyRange
           
    Else
    MsgBox "Range not found"
    'Return
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

After taking BigBen's suggestion and modifying it works great for taking A to H from my sheet "FUZE Dump" to the "Main" B to I, but now I need to also take J to Y from "FUZE Dump" (Same Row) and copy them to AM to BA in "Main" (Same Row) and again everything I have tried just messes up my "Main" sheet.

Comment: `Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A" & j & ":H" & j).Copy Destination:=MyRange`?

Comment: Tried many iterations of that and it always throws "Compile Error Expected: list separator or ) error

Comment: That definitely compiles.

Comment: Which line throws `Compile Error`? Please edit your post to  share the code line.

Comment: My bad I see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CmdBtnUpdate_Click()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'This is the section to pull the updated FUZE information from the dump.
Dim FUZEProjectIDMAIN As String
Dim FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP As String
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim lRow, cRow As Long
Dim RangeToCopy1, RangeToCopy2 As Range
Dim RangeToPaste1, RangeToPaste2 As Range
Dim Row As Integer
lRow = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
For j = lRow To 1 Step -1
If j = 1 Then
MsgBox "Skipping Line 1"
Else
    FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("A" & j)
    'Now that I have my cell value I need to find this in Sheets("Main")
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Main").Range("B:B").Find(FUZEProjectIDFUZEDUMP)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
    Row = MyRange.Row
    Set RangeToCopy1 = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("E" & j & ":F" & j) ', "J" & j & ":Y" & j
    Set RangeToPaste1 = Sheets("Main").Range("F" & Row & ":G" & Row) ', "AM" & Row & ":BA" & Row
    Set RangeToCopy2 = Sheets("FUZE Dump").Range("J" & j & ":Y" & j) ', "J" & j & ":Y" & j
    Set RangeToPaste2 = Sheets("Main").Range("AM" & Row & ":BA" & Row) ', "AM" & Row & ":BA" & Row
    RangeToCopy1.Copy Destination:=RangeToPaste1
    RangeToCopy2.Copy Destination:=RangeToPaste2
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Range not found"
    'Return
    End If
End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Above is my final solution that allowed me to select specific cells in a row from one sheet into a specific row and cells in another!

Comment: I do have one more ask. How can I keep the formatting I have on sheet "Main". When I paste over from sheet "FUZE Dump" it is using that formatting instead :(